# Disallow url with ends with "?m=0" in robots

Tags: robots.txt

Hello I want to disallow urls like this one: "/2018/11/razones-para-ver-fallet.html?m=0", in robots.txt. I mean the ones who ends with "?m=0".

This one belongs to blogger mobile view (now I have migrated to wordpress) and google bot are still indexing (sitemaps in console is the new one but...) them causing some cpu problems.

I have proved with: Disallow: /*?m=0 but I´m still seeing them in visit log.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about this: `Disallow: /*?*m=0`